# nav2d installation

Tags: ros, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the command line: `roslaunch nav2d_tutorials tutorial1.launch`
I get a lot of line that I don't understand where should I look at or how to fix the problem:

```
ResourceNotFound: p2os_urdf
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225026/nav2d-installation/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-01-25**:
I guess it is something related to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH but I'm not sure what the correct path should be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ResourceNotFound` error indicates that you're missing the `p2os_urdf` package. Is it installed?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-01-26**:
How can I check (in which folder) that is installed or not ?
When I try: `sudo find / -name p2os_urdf -type d` then I can't see any path so I guess that is not installed.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-26**:
You can try `rospack find p2os_urdf` to determine if a package is installed or not. In this particular case, it looks like the p2os_urdf package had a regression and was removed from the build farm for some reason: http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2015-November/069765.html

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-26**:
I've filed an issue against p2os for their regression: https://github.com/allenh1/p2os/issues/40 . Until that is fixed, you should probably install p2os from source.

**Comment by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on 2016-05-09**:
Thanks for your advise!